# "@RunWith" class from Cucumber in xUnit SpecFlow

Tags: .net-core, cucumber, xunit, specflow, rider

I have tests written in SpecFlow with xUnit.
I have few feature files with scenarios with different tags.
I want to run tests with specific tag.
In Cucumber we have runner classes with annotations like so:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@foo and not @bar"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

How to "translate" this into SpecFlow with xUnit?
I did read about Traits but this seems to work only when I'm running tests from terminal.
I would want to run tests from one class in IDE like in Cucumber.

[UPDATE]

I'm using IntelliJ Rider as IDE.
For now I'm running tests in three ways:

1. Run single 'feature' file from context menu:

[image]

2. Run all tests from "Unit Tests" tab:

[image]

3. From command line -> this way I can run tests with specific tags:

```
 dotnet test --filter "Category=users"
```

Now, I want to create a runner class, so I can right click on this class and run scenarios with defined there tags, as I can do it from command line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to run tests? Can you show that? Is it C# code or the command line?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you still using IntelliJ Rider to run SpecFlow tests? Or are you using Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes, I'm using Rider to run tests in local (when I'm developing). On server I will run them from command line of course.